# How to enqueue different scripts & styles for a Custom Post Type in functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I have two functions to enqueue my scripts. I want to call one function if the post is a custom post type, and the other for all other posts and pages.

How add conditional logic in functions.php to do this? Typical Wordpress functions(get_the_ID, is_post_type and others) are not working in functions.php.

This is my code:

```
// How Add Conditional Logic ?
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_media_new' );


// Use fot All pages to site
function theme_media() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static/css/main.min.css"' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'common-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static/js/main.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

}
// Use Only for custom post type 'coaching'
function theme_media_new(){

  wp_enqueue_style( 'main-new-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static_new/css/main.min.css"' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'common-new-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static_new/js/main.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

}
```

Comment: Please show us the code & action you use when you are enqueueing the scripts, so we can see where this is happening in your site and be able to help.

Comment: Added code to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the conditional logic into the function you add to `add_action`. In that function you can check for the post type/archive and calof the functions you want for that page.

I'm not sure if you want to do this for a Custom Post Type *archive* or *post* (or both), so I've included the checks for both, you can change the code to suit what you need it to do.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_styles_scripts' );

function my_enqueue_styles_scripts(){

    // load scripts for ALL pages if you have any...

    // Now check for your CPT and load the extra scripts:
    // Load scripts only on CPT POSTS of type "coaching"
    if ( is_singular( 'coaching' ) )
        theme_media_new(); 

    // otherwise load scripts for all other pages
    else
        theme_media();
}
```

If you want to load the scripts on the *archive* page for the custom post types, you can use this instead of `is_singular`

```
    // Load scripts only for the ARCHIVE for the CPT "coaching"
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'coaching' ) ) 
        theme_media_new();
```

Comment: If is _singular('coaching') do not load theme_media

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa I've updated my answer - you just need to add an `else`. Your code said `theme_media` was "*Use fot All pages to site*" so I thought that meant every page. So  I've changed the answer to work like this: if the current page is a CPT coaching post then load `theme_media_new`, for everything else load `theme_media`