# WordPress dynamically include scripts and styles

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a basic bunch of CSS/Js files defined in my functions.php file. There I register and enqueue those scripts and stylesheets.

But in specific situations I want to load additional scripts based on the site template which is used.

I tried to register and enqueue those additional scripts in the specific template file, but it didnt work. It does only work when included in the functions.php.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enqueue different scripts & styles for a Custom Post Type in functions.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63680783/how-to-enqueue-different-scripts-styles-for-a-custom-post-type-in-functions-ph)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_file' );
 
 function enqueue_file() {
  if(is_front() || is_archive()){ // you can set here condition
      wp_enqueue_style( 'main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . 
      '/static/css/main.min.css"' ); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your functions.php in child theme:

```
add_action(
    'wp_enqueue_scripts',
    'loadActionFrontend'
);


function loadActionFrontend()
{
    if( is_page( 'pageid here' ) ) {
        wp_register_script(
            'scriptName',
            'scripturl',
            [],
            '',
            true
        );

        wp_enqueue_script('scriptName');
    }
}
```

with the query `if( is_page( 'pageid here' ) )` you can insert your desired pageid where the script shold loaded.